# What is the proper method to use the results of one compute shader in the next compute shader

Tags: swift, metal, compute-shader

Suppose I dispatch two compute shaders A and B in metal. I don't want B to run until after A has completed. At the moment I am encoding each shader in their own command buffer and committing like so:

```
commandBufferA.commit()
commandBufferA.waitUntilCompleted()
commandBufferB.commit()
```

Is this the proper technique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `waitUntilCompleted()` on a command buffer is useful if you need to use the results of a kernel back on the CPU, but is unnecessary and inefficient if your intent is simply to use the result of a compute command (dispatch) in a subsequent compute command. If there is a data dependency between compute commands, the results written by the former are guaranteed to be visible to the latter, even within a single command buffer. So, you could structure it something like this:

```
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()

commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineStateA)
commandEncoder.setTexture(inputTexture, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setTexture(intermediateTexture, at: 1)
commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupCount, 
                                    threadsPerThreadgroup: threadgroupSize)

commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineStateB)
commandEncoder.setTexture(intermediateTexture, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setTexture(outputTexture, at: 1)
commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupCount, 
                                    threadsPerThreadgroup: threadgroupSize)

commandEncoder.endEncoding()
commandBuffer.commit()

commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted() // optional; only if you need to read the result on the CPU
```

Comment: Could this be applied to your image filtering chapter of MBE to improve performance? If I remember correctly each filter that is chained has its own command encoder?

Comment: Encoders themselves are pretty cheap, but the sample you're referring to has the problem illustrated by this question: it creates a command buffer for every dispatch and does a CPU wait so it can provide results synchronously. If I were doing it all over again, with the benefit of hindsight and the exemplar of Metal Performance Shaders, I'd make it asynchronous and also ensure that multiple filters encoded their work into the same buffer. Live and learn.

Comment: Note that if you are ping-ponging textures you need to at least commit.